# Explicitly saving the file using fstream without closing the file in C++

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream, ofstream

WRT code, i want to **explicitly** "save" the file without calling close(). i know there is no need to call close() as fsteam will call the destructor and save the file when fstream object goes out of scope.

> But i want to "explictly" save the file without waiting for fstream
>   object to go out of scope.  Is there a way to do this in C++ ?
>   Is there anything like

```
flHtmlFile.save()
```

The only 1 option i know is to close it & open again ?

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ofstream flHtmlFile;
    std::string fname = "some.txt";
    flHtmlFile.open(fname);
    flHtmlFile << "text1"; // gets written
    flHtmlFile.close(); // My purpose is to EXPLICITLY SAVE THE FILE. Is there anything like flHtmlFile.save()
    flHtmlFile << "text2"; // doesn't get written 'coz i called close()
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You seem to want to flush to the file?

Comment: @codeLover: **Why do you ask?** Please **edit your question** to motivate it !

Comment: @codeLover: Could you please *motivate* your question (and give more details: what operating system, what C++ compiler and C++ & C standard libraries, what file system, what application)? How critical is it to avoid losing data (is your system a life-threatening real-time critical embedded system like in an airplane or a nuclear power plant)?

Comment: Without additional motivation, the question stays unclear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files are often some stream of bytes, and could be much bigger than your virtual address space (e.g. you can have a terabyte sized file on a machine with only a few gigabytes of RAM).

In general a program won't keep all the content of a file in memory.

Some libraries enable you to read or write all the content at once in memory  (if it fits there!). E.g. [Qt](http://qt.io/) has a [QFile](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html) class with an inherited [readAll](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readAll) member function.

However, file streams (either `FILE` from C standard library, or `std::ostream` from C++ standard library) are buffered. You may want to flush the buffer. Use [std::flush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) (in C++) or [fflush](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) (in C); they practically often issue some [system calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) (probably [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) on Linux) to ask the operating system to write some data in some file (but they probably don't guarantee that the data has reached the disk).

What *exactly* happens is file system-, operating system-, and hardware- specific. On Linux, the [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) may keep the data before it is written to disk (so if the computer loses power, data might be lost). And [disk controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_controller) hardware also have RAM and are somehow buffering. See also [sync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sync.2.html) and [fsync(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fsync.2.html) (and even [posix_fadvise(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/posix_fadvise.2.html)...). So even if you flush some stream, you are not sure that the bytes are permanently written on the disk (and you usually don't care).

<sup>(there are *many layers* and *lots of buffering* between your C++ code and the real hardware)</sup>

BTW you might write into memory thru [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) in C++ (or [open_memstream](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/open_memstream.3.html) in C on POSIX), flush that stream, then do something with its memory data (e.g. [write(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) it to disk).

Comment: thanks. Curious what's the difference between "flHtmlFile.flush();" as StoryTeller suggessted & std::flush() ? WHich is most performance friendly.

Comment: I don't know and I believe you should really not care (I still don't understand what motivates your question). If performance is such an issue, you need to benchmark.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want is for the content you wrote to reach the file system as soon as possible, then call `flush` on the file:

```
flHtmlFile.flush();
```

No closing or re-opening required.

Comment: Great answer; minor additions: 1. This does not necessarily block until the data has been written to the disk. 2. `std::endl` appends a newline and flushes. Depending on your use case, this may reduce the need for calling the flush() method. 3. You can also use `std::flush` (similar to `std::endl`), if you prefer the syntax over a method call.

Comment: @MarkusMayr - Thanks :) But at this point I'd rather just upvote Basile's answer and encourage the OP to accept it.